# Displaying data from a column of my dataframe in a web page

Tags: python, html, django, pandas, numpy

I want to display the rows of a column of my dataframe in a web page. I get an error on the following line:

```
return render(requete, 'analyse/index.html', context={'data': df['EXTERNAL_DATA2'].tolist()})
```

Below is the error that is displayed:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: `javascript` tag is misleading and probably `pandas` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably (based on the error message) `df` is not a `pandas.DataFrame` object but a `list`. Depending on its inner structure you might try (untested)

```
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(df)

return render(requete, 'analyse/index.html', context={'data': df2['EXTERNAL_DATA2'].tolist()})
```

In general you should debug data-related problems outside of your web application. Django and randering your data to html only adds unnecessary complexity here. I would recommend, to use jupyter or ipython to interactively explore your data only then process it in the webapp.

Comment: I have no more errors but it returns nothing. Please do you know why?

Comment: `df = df.loc[(df['EXTERNAL_DATA1'] == 'dataBundle') & (df['EXTERNAL_DATA2'].str.contains(
            'Bundle_Weekly_400MB|Bundle_Daily_40MB|Bundle_Daily_150MB|Bundle_Daily_10MB|Bundle_Weekly_100MB',
            na=False))]
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(df)

        return render(requete, 'analyse/index.html', context={'data': df2['EXTERNAL_DATA2'].tolist()})`

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (e.g. by editing your question). Again: my advice is to leave django out of the way and solve the data-type-related issues first.